# Move a partition to the right using command line tools

Tags: linux, partition, sfdisk, move-partition

I have a partition, say 190 GB, followed by 100 GB of unpartitioned disk free space.

I want to move this partition 100GB "to the right" (towards a higher sector number), so that the free unpartitioned free space would then be on the left of it.

This partition cannot just be copied carelessly, because:

- it contains encrypted data that must be preserved (on the block level),
- there is an overlap between the old and new position of the partition.

I know GParted should be able to handle this. However I would like to do it myself with command line tools. I know `sfdisk` [has something](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sfdisk.8.html) like this to move partition 100M to the right:

```sh
echo '+100M,' | sfdisk --move-data /dev/sdc -N 1
```

I'd like to know 2 things:

- **If I was to move data manually, using tools like `dd` (or others), how would I do that?** I believe the end of the partition must be copied before the start of it, like a backward read-and-copy (of course, I would also need to edit the GPT partition table).
- If I want to use `sfdisk`, how can I use it so that I shift by a very precise sector number, so that it properly "touches" the partition that is on the far end of the disk? (so that they are really next to each other with no gap in between)

Comment: `dd` is not the right tool for this. You would have to manually make sure the partition sizes are correct before and after the copy and that the partition tables match what your just dd'ed to the raw disk. If `sfdisk` does what you want and their commands have been vetted, go with an accepted tool.

Comment: Side note: you say "move partition", but you want to move the partition and the filesystem within it. Windows often *pretends* partitions are filesystems, in Linux we should know better. Moving a partition is fast and easy, all you need to do is to update the partition table. If there was no filesystem (yet or at all) inside the partition, there would be no problem. Moving the existing *filesystem* to match the new partition is the non-trivial task your question is about. Thus I say the title should be "move a partition with filesystem…" or so.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, the partition contains encrypted data that must be preserved, I edited my question.

Comment: @doneal24 so, what is the right tool then? `dd` can work pretty well for moving a partition "backwards" (as it reads forward by default)

Comment: Probably GNU `ddrescue` with `--reverse` and `--max-read-errors=0` can be (ab)used. It won't be as straightforward as `sfdisk --move-data`, but if you overcome few obstacles and set all the relevant parameters right then one invocation of `ddrescue` will do the job. So it's not as "manually" as with `dd`, where you need to run a loop and calculate offsets in each iteration. Note [you should only ask *practical*, answerable questions based on *actual* problems that you face](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). "If I was…?" does not fit. "I don't have `sfdisk` …" may fit if it's true.

Comment: Thank you @KamilMaciorowski! With `sfdisk` I wouldn't be sure of the offset I can use and I fear that I cannot control exactly where on the disk the partition is shifted... So I felt more confident with other tools. But, yes, a precise answer with `sfdisk` would also be interesting for me (as the doc is ok, but not so precise). I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: The way to do stuff like this is to start by taking backups :) The fact that the data is encrypted _shouldn't_ be an issue, as it's still data, and anyway _most_ (if not all) stuff used inside partitions considers disk positions relative the start or end of the surrounding partition (or whatever container it is, could be e.g. a full disk too). So the problem is just about moving the data to the correct position. But the overlap makes it a bit iffy, it would be much easier if you could copy the data off, recreate the partition in the new place and copy the data back.

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to use `sfdisk`, how can I use it so that I shift by a very
> precise sector number, so that it properly "touches" the partition
> that is on the far end of the disk? (so that they are really next to
> each other with no gap in between)

You do that by providing the number of sectors as input to `sfdisk`:

```
echo '+NUM' | sfdisk --move-data /dev/sdc -N 1
```

will move the 1st partition `NUM` sectors to the right.
As explained in the manual

> **A numerical argument is by default interpreted as a number of sectors**

Only when `NUM` is followed by a multiplicative suffix (like `M`, `KiB` etc) will `sfdisk` treat it as a size in bytes (e.g. `+50GiB`).

---

How do you know the number of sectors? Simple, `sfdisk` will report it via the `-F` switch:

> `-F, --list-free [device...]`
> List the free unpartitioned areas on all or the specified devices.

Sample output (I marked the no. of sectors of the free area in bold):

```
    Start       End    Sectors   Size
114369428 324084628  209715200   100G
```

so using that number as `NUM` in the first command:

```
echo '+209715200' | sfdisk --move-data /dev/sdc -N 1
```

will move the 1st partition next to the following one with no gap in between.

---

For the record, here it is in action on a 2GB sd-card (non-relevant parts of output removed):
There were 4 partitions, I deleted the 3rd one, so as to have free space following the 2nd partition that I will then move next to last partition. I start by listing the existing partitions:

```
sfdisk -l /dev/sdc  

[...]

Device    Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1         2048 2099199 2097152    1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2      2099200 2488319  389120  190M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc4      2693120 3966975 1273856  622M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Partition `sdc2`, that I want to move, ends at sector `2488319`, so the free space starts at sector `2488320`. I then list free space areas:

```
sfdisk -F /dev/sdc

Unpartitioned space /dev/sdc: 101,5 MiB, 106430464 bytes, 207872 sectors
[...]

  Start     End Sectors  Size
2488320 2693119  204800  100M
3966976 3970047    3072  1,5M
```

There are two free space areas - I need the no. of sectors for the one that starts at `2488320`... I then use that number - `204800` - as input to `sfdisk` to move partition no.2:

```
echo '+204800' | sfdisk /dev/sdc  -N 2 --move-data
```

```
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ... OK

[...]

Old situation:

Device    Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1         2048 2099199 2097152    1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2      2099200 2488319  389120  190M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc4      2693120 3966975 1273856  622M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

New situation:

Device    Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1         2048 2099199 2097152    1G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc2      2304000 2693119  389120  190M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sdc4      2693120 3966975 1273856  622M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Data move:
  start sector: (from/to) 2099200 / 2304000
  sectors: 389120
  step size: 1048576 bytes

Moved 389120 from 389120 sectors (100%).

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Per the `New situation:` output, partition `2` end sector is now `2693119` and partition `4` start sector is `2693120`, i.e. no gap in between.